# PostgreSQL work_mem with spring framework

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

PostgreSQL work_mem with spring framework

It's possible to increase work_mem for one special query which is implemented with Spring Framework?

My repository class is:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountSpringRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

...

    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Account a here_is_the_query> now())")
    List<Account> findAccountByStatus(
            @Param("status") List<EnumStatusType> status,
            Pageable limit);
}
```

It's possible and how to increase work_mem for the given query?

```
SET work_mem = '256MB';
```

Regards,
Rafal

Comment: Did you try `@Query(value = "set work_mem = '128MB'; SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Account a here_is_the_query> now())")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in the framework specifically, but the way this is done in general is:

- start a transaction
- run

  ```
  SET LOCAL work_mem = '256MB';  --valid only for the transaction
  ```
- run your query
- commit the transaction

Comment: I know this with LOCAL. But without LOCAL this sould be changed for all followed queries. Why I can't see the new value, when I call "SHOW work_mem" in pgAdmin? I have to evalute the change before we put this on production.

Comment: `SET` changes the parameter only for the current session. Do you really want this for *all* queries? Do you have low enough `max_connections` to afford such a high value? If yes, you'd set it in `postgresql.conf` and reload to activate it.

Comment: I changed it only fo the current trancaction.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

`@Modifying
@Query(value = "SET work_mem = '128MB'", nativeQuery = true)
void setWorkMem();`

and this:

`statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("SET work_mem = '128MB';");
statement.execute("insert into public.test values('trest')");`

And when I call "SHOW work_mem" than I get the DEFAULT value back. And in the postgresql log I see:

`LOG:  Ausführen <unnamed>: SET work_mem = '128MB' -> called from Java code`

and not

`LOG:  Anweisung: -- SET work_mem = '128MB'; -> called from pgAdmin`

Why?